# Run gdb inside docker container running systemd

Tags: docker, systemd, linux-capabilities

I was able to start a docker container running systemd using

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8022:22 -e container=docker debug-image /sbin/init
```

However, gdb was not able to debug C processes in this environment, because it lacked the required `SYS_PTRACE` capability.

I tried adding `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` to the `docker run` command line, but then `systemd` appeared to hang on startup (it printed nothing to the terminal). The same thing happened when I tried passing `--privileged` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command worked:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8022:22 --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -e container=docker --privileged debug-image /sbin/init
```