# GDBServer not starting or listening on port when run inside of Docker

Tags: docker, debugging, rust, clion, gdbserver

I am trying to compile a "hello world" Rust program inside a Docker container and then remotely debug it using GDBServer and CLion, but I don't think `gdbserver` is starting correctly. When I start it, I don't get the "process started" and "listening on port..." messages I expect; I get nothing.

I have successfully done this with a Raspberry Pi on my home network, but can't get it to work when using Docker.

My ultimate goal is to deploy this Docker container on a Digital Ocean droplet and debug remotely from my local machine. For now, I've got Docker running on the local machine.

I am working on a Mac (Mojave), running Docker (v18.09), and spinning up a Docker container that is [an image built from Debian with Rust and `gdbserver` installed](https://github.com/schickling/dockerfiles/tree/master/rust). GDBServer and Rust are installed by:

```sh
# install curl (needed to install rust)
apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gdb g++-multilib lib32stdc++6 libssl-dev libncurses5-dev

# install rust + cargo nightly
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y --default-toolchain nightly
```

I start the container with `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/source -p 7777:7777 schickling/rust` which starts up `bash` by default.

Once in the container, I compile the Rust program using `rustc -g -o ./program ./src/main.rs` which outputs a single file: `program`. I can run the program fine (it only outputs `Hello World`).

When I run `gdbserver localhost:7777 ./program` inside Docker, the terminal just hangs. I've let it sit for 20 minutes. I can't connect to it from CLion, and even `ping` doesn't work from my Mac. I've tried adding the `--debug` flag which outputs `my_waitpid (11, 0x0)` and then hangs. I've also tried `:7777`, `127.0.0.1:7777`, and `host:7777`. I've tried several different ports.

I'm not sure where my problem is. It may be that GDBServer *is* running and the issue is in my CLion setup, but I doubt it. I have path mappings setup and `target remote args` is `tcp:127.0.0.1:7777`. I just get `Connection closed`. Symbol File and Sys Root are empty, but that has worked in the past with my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: If I run gdb inside the container, can I use my IDE *outside* the container to step through it? I've been searching for "existing solutions" and have come up with a couple articles, but none have worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how to run my Docker container as `--privileged` which allows `gdbserver` to run correctly. I also updated some of my CLion configs and got it working.

The useful links:

- https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/linux/docker/
- [Run gdb inside docker container running systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773691/run-gdb-inside-docker-container-running-systemd)
- [gdb does not hit any breakpoints when I run it from inside Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856092/gdb-does-not-hit-any-breakpoints-when-i-run-it-from-inside-docker-container)
- https://github.com/mdklatt/clion-remote

My updated docker command `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/source -p 7777:7777 -e container=docker --privileged schickling/rust`

And my Run configuration:

- GDB: Bundled
- 'target remote' args: tcp:localhost:7777
- Symbolfile: The local copy of my compiled binary (copied from Docker thanks to volumes)
- Sysroot: (blank)
- Pathmappings: The absolute path to my project directory in Docker, and the absolute path to the same project directory on my local machine (the same volume)

Works like a charm.

Comment: Instead of `--privileged`, `--cap-add SYS_PTRACE` should work as well and give less privileges to the container.